# Blue Yeti Nano USB microphone, can I use it with headphone microphone?

Tags: yeti-nano

I have alarge  "Blue Yeti Nano" microphone. It has a headset jack plug connector.
I plug my headset into  it and I can hear sound output, so good so far. But my headset has its own microphone. When I set as system default soundinput device to Yeti Nano, it takes sound from the big microphone, but not  from the headphone's own microphone, which is a lot more convenient. How to fix this?
Thank you!:)
System: Windows-10

Comment: Your Blue Yeti Nano only have a headphone TRS jack, likely, and so does not support your headset's microphone. If you wish to use your headset's microphone, connect your headset to the computer directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found specification details yet, but I am willing to bet the TRS jack on the Blue Yeti Nano is speakers only. Due to the design of that connector, you can connect a headset (with mic) and it will fit, but the mic will not work because it is not connected to anything.

If you wish to use your headset's microphone you should not be connecting this through the Blue Yeti, but to the computer itself directly.